# Finding a sequence of continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying for my analysis functions and we've been working on sequences on functions.  One of the practice questions we were given asks us to find a sequence of continuous functions $f_n : [0,1] \to\ \mathbb R$ that converges *pointwise* to a continuous function and $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)dx ≠ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$$

We are also asked to find a sequence of continuous functions with all the same conditions, except converging uniformly to a *continuous* function.

I really have no idea where to begin with this.  Any ideas what these sequences of functions should be?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first question consider a sequence of functions $f_n$ with a spike on $[0, 2/n]$, with peak in $1/n$ such that the integral is always $=1$ say. For the second one have another look at the theorems you have learned about uniform convergence and integration.

Comment: Do you know any theorems about integrals of a uniformly convergent sequence of functions?

Comment: @TedShifrin Looking at the theorem in my book about if (f_n) converges uniformly to f, then f is Riemann integrable.  But it also says that in that case, lim of the integral of (f_n) IS equal to the integral of f.  Which isn't supposed to hold true for this question.  So I'm not sure I understand where you're going with that

Comment: @Thomas, are you saying that the "spike" on [0, 2/n] and the "peak" at 1/n are the same thing?  Can you maybe give me an example of that kind of function?  I find this explanation unclear.

Comment: Well, you've answered the second question. There can be no such example.

Comment: No. A spike in this case is, e.g., a continuous function linear increasing on $[0,1/n]$, then linear decreasing on $[1/n, 2/n]$ with its maximum (the peak) at $1/n$. If you choose the peak at an appropriate height, you can control the value of the integral.